# Redirect to an action from a class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have been researching this and no luck. Is it possible to redirectToAction from a class. I moved my code from my controller to a class because it was too long. I will like to redirectToAction and user this method in my controller.

```
 return RedirectToAction("CreateReportFile", "Home", new { result = strObj.ToString() });
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Can you explain more about what you're trying to achieve, and why you think you need to redirect from a class other than a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` is a method on your controller, so you'd need to pass the controller instance to your class:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass(this);
    return myClass.Bar();
}
```

I wouldn't call that good code though. You could instead act on the return value from the method in your class:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    var result = myClass.Bar();

    if (result == "baz") // bool, Enum, whatever you like
    {
        return RedirectToAction(
            "CreateReportFile",
            "Home",
            new { result = myClass.StrObj.ToString() }
            );
    }
    else
    {
        //
    }
}
```